# Flatten a parent child structure to a BehaviorSubject that resolves to an array

Tags: typescript, rxjs, flatten, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviourSubject` that resolves into a collection where each item of has a property `children` that also is a `BehaviourSubject` resolving into a collection of items.
Now I want to subscribe to my subject and flatten the whole thing into an array where I have a row for each item and each child.

So something in the line of:

```
interface Parent = {
  children: BehaviorSubject<Child[]>
}
```

Now I want to make another behavior subject out of this that resolves into an array where I have an item for each parent followed by its children.

Starting with:

```
const collection: BehaviorSubject<Parent[]>;
```

Want to result to:

```
const behaviourSubject: BehaviorSubject<(Parent|Child)[]>;

behaviourSubject.subscribe((result: (Parent|Child)[]) => { 
  ...desired result... 
});
```

So let's say the first `Parent` in the collection has 3 children, and second has 2 children then if I subscribe to the resulting `behaviourSubject` the output should look like this.

```
result: [Parent, Child, Child, Child, Parent, Child, Child];
```

How do I achieve this.

I tried to figure out how to do this, by reading in the documentation of RxJS and checking examples, but I guess the recent lack of sleep seems to make my brain work like a dry sponge and I thought the best right now would be to call out for some help on StackOverflow.

**Note**: if the parent collection or the children get a new value, the result should be updated as well...

Comment: you going to put parent which contains the child in the array too ?

Comment: @FanCheung Yes, I need both the parents and the children in the array in their respective order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below show work, but I wonder why you use BehaviorSubject to add up the complexity

```
import { first, switchMap, toArray, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe, BehaviorSubject, from } from 'rxjs';

//...

const parent1={children:new BehaviorSubject([{name:'john'},{name:'may'},{name:'betty'}])}

const parent2={children:new BehaviorSubject([{name:'key'},{name:'tom'}])}

const collection=new BehaviorSubject([parent1,parent2]);

collection.pipe(
  first(),
  switchMap(parent=>from(parent)),
  switchMap(p=>p.children.pipe(first(),map(c=>[p,...c]))),
  toArray(),
  map(arr=>arr.flat())
).subscribe(console.log)
```

if you dont mind make use the .value property from BehaviourSubject the code can be reduced to below

```
collection.value.map(p=>[p,...p.children.value]).flat()
```

### EDIT (BY OP):

I will edit this question for those wondering about the different steps in this answer I broke it down in pieces. 
It can also be found in **[this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-e9xgpn?file=index.ts)** to play around with.

Constructing the data:

```
import { first, switchMap, toArray, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe, BehaviorSubject, from } from 'rxjs';

class Child {
  constructor(public name: string){
  }
}

class Parent {
  constructor(public children: BehaviorSubject<Child[]>){
  }
}

const collection = new BehaviorSubject([
  new Parent(new BehaviorSubject([
    new Child('john'),
    new Child('may'),
    new Child('betty'),
  ])),
  new Parent(new BehaviorSubject([
    new Child('key'),
    new Child('tom'),
  ])),
]);
```

Here the final observable with its different operations in the pipes with comments added to explain what they exactly do when subscribing to the result:

```
collection.pipe(
  //Emit the first value 
  first(),
  // Complete previous inner observable, emit values
  switchMap((parents: Parent[]) => { 
    // Emit array as a sequence of values
    return from(parents)
  }),
  // complete previous inner observable, emit values
  switchMap((parent: Parent) => { 
    return parent.children.pipe(
      // Emit the first value 
      first(),
      // Apply projection with each value from source
      map(
        (children: Child[]) => {
          // return desired array for each parent
          return [parent, ...children];
        }
      )
    )
  }),
  //Collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes
  toArray(),
  //map(arr=>arr.flat())
  map((array: (Parent|Child)[][] ) => {
    // Flatten the array
    return array.flat();
  }),
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Hej, thanks for your answer. I will check out this solution. I use `BehaviorSubject`, since they reflect objects that can receive new values (new items and changed properties) through some real-time service logic. Like that my views will update automatically when new data arrives. Those nested objects are reflecting other endpoints (relational data). But if you see a possibility to simplify it without using `BehaviorSubject` while keeping changing things in real-time working I am open for suggestions of course!

Comment: If behavior subject is keep emitting u won’t be able to reduce the result to an array but u can use scan operator to emit the latest accumulated array

Comment: It worked, thanks! I added the needed import statements to the answer. I accidentally imported `switchMap` from another location resulting in some unexpected errors; it will help me and other people in future.